# about:blank in src

Tags: php, html, embed, src

I'm getting "`about:blank`" in my `src=""`

```
<form action="check.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="POP2!">
    <input type="hidden" name="video" value='<embed src="http://XXXXX" width="712" height="475" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always">'>
</form>
```

In my check.php:

```
$output = $_POST['video'];
$output = urldecode($output);
echo $output;
```

The value of $_POST['video'] gets to.

```
<embed src="about:blank" width="712" height="475" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always">
```

Anyone know why the link changes to about:blank?
Thanks.

Edit: Google Chrome - Inspect Element error show this

```
Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request.
```

Comment: Wow this is some weird stuff: `<input type="hidden" name="video" value='<embed src="http://XXXXX" width="712" height="475" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always">'>`. You might want to html encode that? (Unrelated) **EDIT** Hm maybe it's not so unrelated =) Encode it!

Comment: Why would you have a hidden field with a tag as value instead of the video url ? And why are you still using `<embed>` in this day and age.

Comment: @Rudie I just did, thanks for the suggestion. Problem still stands. @teresko What do you mean? embed is still used today, huh?

Comment: . sure .. like table-based layout and BMP files `<img />` tags ... but it doesn't mean that its correct to do it : http://alistapart.com/articles/byebyeembed

Answer (score 2):

Are you checking the value of `$_POST['video']` in the debugger or in the browser?

Also, if you are using Firefox/Chrome, do you have an extesion called **Flashblock** (or any other Flash blocking extension) installed? Apparently they can cause this sort of behaviour if you're checking the output in the browser.

Comment: I viewed it in "Google Chrome" - "Inpect Elemets" and got the about:blank in there. When I view the code in "View Source code" It shows the correct code, but it does not make the video into a VIDEO. It shows blank page.

Answer (score 2):

you could send a 'X-XSS-Protection: 0' header  in the check.php

reference to this issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83503